# Limit amount of records retrieved when using Doctrine DQL in Symfony2

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, symfony, dql

I have the following query:

```
   $latestcontent = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT c.title, c.content, c.lastedit, a.firstname, a.surname
            FROM ShoutMainBundle:Content c, ShoutMainBundle:Admin a
            WHERE c.author = a.id
            ORDER BY c.lastedit ASC'
            );
```

What I need to do, is limit the amount of records returned from this query. However, when I add LIMIT 10 to the SQL query, it returns this error:

> Error: Expected end of string, got 'LIMIT'.

So, I had a look and found that you could do add `->limit(10)` to the code (after the query). But this then throws up this PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::limit() in C:\wamp\www\src\Shout\AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 22
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is no statement like LIMIT for DQL currently, as far as I know.

You have to use [Query::setMaxResults()](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result).

Comment: That's worked, thank you. It's confused me a slight bit as on this page it says there is a limit command (which was what i was using): http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language. But your way works, thank you :)

Comment: @mickburkejnr: The link you provided in your comment is for Doctrine 1.2. Symfony2 is using Doctrine 2.1, so the documentation you read doesn't match the version you are using. This [link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.1/docs/hu) is for the Doctrine 2.1 documentation.

Comment: @matt is right, the link I provided was 1.1 (I didn't know). This is the one thing that annoys me most about the new Symfony. The documentation is all over the place.

Comment: Link for Doctrine 2.6: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result (when using QueryBuilder)