# SQL query with count and group by in Symfony2 QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I need your help please. I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS count FROM mytable GROUP BY email ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But I would like to do this in Symfony2 with Doctrine and the createQueryBuilder().
I try this, but didn't work :

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$db->andWhere('COUNT( * ) AS count');
$db->groupBy('s.email');
$db->orderBy('s.id', 'DESC');
```

Can you help me please ? Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean with *didn't work*? How to `LIMIT` your Doctrine results was answered [here before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7404238/1847340)

Answer (score 8):

You need to run 2 queries:

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$db
    ->select('s')
    ->groupBy('s.email')
    ->orderBy('s.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(30);

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$db
    ->select('count(s)')
    ->groupBy('s.email')
    //->orderBy('s.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1);

$qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Wrong answer, it leads not to the same result as in initial query in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use

```
$query->select('COUNT(DISTINCT u)');
```

and it's seem to work fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder('mytable');
$db
    ->addSelect('COUNT(*) as count')
    ->groupBy('mytable.email')
    ->orderBy('mytable.id', 'DESC')
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(30);
$result = $db->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Hope it helps even if it's an old stack